# Sequelize - case-insensitive like

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I achieve this in Sequelize?

```
SELECT * FROM table where lower(column) LIKE ('abcd%');
```

I can't find a way to mix *lower* function with *$like*

Comment: I learned that in MySQL you don't need to call `lower()` on the column.  `Like` is implicitly a case-insensitive search.  YMMV depending on your colation/character set if it's not `utf8`.

Comment: Also to add on all no binary (varchar, text) string comparisons in mysql are not case sensitive at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
Table.findAll({
  attributes: ['createdAt', 'col'],
  where: {
    $and:[
      {
        createdAt:{
          $between:[minDate, maxDate]
        }
      },
      Sequelize.where(
        Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('col')),
        {
          $like: 'abcd%'
        }
      )
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: What was the solution? the % sign?

Comment: The solution was the combination between `where()` and `fn()`

Comment: So what's the new way with...

"Unhandled rejection Error: Support for `{where: 'raw query'}` has been removed." ? 

Like many "slightly advanced but not horrifically terrible" things in SQL where Sequelize is in the mix, I find just spinning through and doing it long hand ends up being slower, but far more readable and maintainable when looking back at the code 6 months or a year later. :\

Comment: I had to add the table name (defined in the corresponding model) in the col method :
`Sequelize.col('table.col')`

Answer (score 38):

You should use Sequelize.Op :

```
Table.findAll({
    where: {
        name: {
            [Sequelize.Op.iLike]: searchQuery
        }
    }
})
```

Don't forget to add % before or after your searchQuery, if you want to make a partial query.

[See the docs here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html)

Comment: FWIW, MySQL doesn't support ILIKE

Comment: This is for PG only

Answer (score 11):

If you're using PostGres, you can use the $iLike operator to search rows (NOT column names like your question asks).

[Sequelize Docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators)

While it doesn't fully address your question, hopefully it will help someone down the road who searches for case-insensitive + Sequelize, which brought me here.

```
Table.findAll({
    where: {
        createdAt: {
            $between: [minDate, maxDate]
        },
        someOtherColumn: {
            $like: '%mysearchterm%'
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar problem and solved by

```
const values = ['adcd'].map(x => x.toLowerCase());

const results = await SomeModel.findAll({
   attributes: [
      ...Object.keys(SomeModel.rawAttributes),
      [Sequelize.fn('LOWER', Sequelize.col('someColumn')), 'lower'],
   ],
   having: { lower: values, },
});
```